# how to provides xml request as variable in php

Tags: php, json, xml, xml-parsing

I want to pass xml request as a variable in php

my xml request looks like

```
$XPost ="<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <REQVERSION>1</REQVERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>COLLECTION</TYPE>
        <SESSIONID>" .$session. "</SESSIONID>
        <TOKEN>" .$token. "</TOKEN>
        <ID>GetProfitnLossColl</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
    <DESC>
    <STATICVARIABLES>
        <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>" .$company. "</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
        <SVEXPORTFORMAT> $$SysName:XML </SVEXPORTFORMAT>
    </STATICVARIABLES>
    <TDL>
    <TDLMESSAGE>
        <COLLECTION NAME= \" GetProfitnLossColl \" ISMODIFY= \" No \" ISFIXED= \" No \" ISINITIALIZE= \" No \" ISOPTION= \" No \" ISINTERNAL= \" No \">
            <TYPE>Group</TYPE>                        
            <CHILDOF>&#4; Primary</CHILDOF>
            <NATIVEMETHOD>parent, MasterID</NATIVEMETHOD>
            <NATIVEMETHOD>BSDrClosing</NATIVEMETHOD>
            <NATIVEMETHOD>BSCrClosing</NATIVEMETHOD>
            <Method>VSPLName   : $$Name</Method>
            <Method>isGroup    : $$IsGroup</Method>
            <Method>cmpName    : ##SVCurrentCompany</Method>
            <Filters>CLDrBalNotZero</Filters>
        </COLLECTION>
        <SYSTEM TYPE= \" Formulae \" NAME= \" CLDrBalNotZero \" ISMODIFY= \" No \" ISFIXED= \" No \" ISINTERNAL= \" No \">$BSDrClosing != 0 Or $BSCrClosing != 0 </SYSTEM>
    </TDLMESSAGE>
    </TDL>
    </DESC>
    </BODY>
    </ENVELOPE>";
```

i am using this request in php to connect Tally Server as

```
<?php
$response = array("error" => FALSE);
if(isset($_REQUEST['session1']) && isset($_REQUEST['token']) && isset($_REQUEST['company']) ){ //&& !empty($_POST['session1']) && !empty($_POST['token']) && !empty($_POST['company']) ){

$url        = "https://dev1.tallyenterprise.com";
//$url      = "https://tallynet.tallyenterprise.com";
$session    = $_REQUEST['session1'];
$token      = $_REQUEST['token'];
$company    = $_REQUEST['company']; ///_POST['company'];

$XPost = "above xml request"                

$headers    = array();
$headers[]  = 'ID:GETPROFITNLOSSCOLL';  //GetProfitnLossColl
$headers[]  = 'SOURCE:VISIONSERVER';
$headers[]  = 'TARGET: TALLY';
$headers[]  = 'CONTENT-TYPE:text/xml;charset=utf-8';
$headers[]  = 'Accept-Encoding:identity';

$headers[]  = 'TARGETACCOUNTINTERNALID:201214173';
//$headers[]    = 'TARGETCOMPANYNAME:Vision Solutions App';
$headers[]  = 'TARGETCOMPANYNAME:'.$company;


//  http://www.hackingwithphp.com/15/10/2/your-first-curl-scripts
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $XPost); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
}
else{
$response["error"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (session or token) is missing!";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

its giving me warning in browser 
Notice: Undefined variable: SysName in C:\wamp64\www\VisionServer\TallyPhp\Req\getProfitnLoss.php on line 36

and Name, IsGroup, BSCrClosing

and response as invalid request

please help me out .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is parsing $SysName:XML as a variable. If you want to send the literal string '$$SysName:XML' you need to escape every dollar sign in the XML string like this:

```
<SVEXPORTFORMAT> \$\$SysName:XML </SVEXPORTFORMAT>
```

Comment: Thank you @Bert i made changes, now it is not shoving error but it shows "invalid request" if i test it in browser by passing parameters in url while in my app i am sending POST request then it shows "Required parameters (session or token) is missing!". Any Solutions...??